# How to play animation forward and backward in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello there :) I'm making a 2d platform game with Unity and got stuck with the crouch animation... I have quite a few frames for crouching, so, when player presses appropriate button character sits down and when the button is released I want this animation to be played backward, so, character stands up. Currently in the animator I created two states with the crouching animation assigned to them. Crouch state speed is 1 and so called un-crouch one is -1 which sort of works fine. My inner perfectionist's question: is there more elegant solution for this kind of cases that allows not to "duplicate" states?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Provide some code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: It’s been done almost without coding. Of course, it could also be achieved programmatically but I prefer to use scripts when it’s really necessary ;)

Comment: As you wish, but it could help people to answer your question. It’s always easier to fix incorrect code than write the whole solution from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can try is to add in your script a parameter to multiply the speed of the animation. You can call this parameters animDirection or something like this.

I am not sure if you want to speed up the animation as well, but just in case you can do something like this:

```
float animSpeed = 1;
float animDirection = 1;
```

Now you can manipulate in your script this variables, to make the animation move faster  and also forward (animDirection = 1) or backward (animDirection = -1)

```
gameObject.animation["crouch"].speed = animSpeed * animDirection;
```

So with this you don't need to have two different states.

Comment: Seems like this trick is the best way to go for now... I was hoping I missed some settings in animation, transition or stuff like that. Checked tons of tutorials but they didn't really cover this aspect (most of them have one frame animation to sit down/stand up).